# Accessing individual bytes of a struct using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I have an application where I need to perform a CRC operation on a struct. I decided the best way to accomplish this would be to simply iterate through all of the individual bytes that make the struct and add them to the CRC routine. The strict is named *Config* and is of type *ConfigT*. The following code describes roughly what I want to do, I just need to get the syntax down for accessing a byte of the struct using pointer arithmetic.

```
 uint16_t CalculateEepromChecksum()
 {
  uint16_t crc = 0;
  uint8_t *ptr = &Config;

   for (uint32_t i = 0; i < sizeof(ConfigT); i++)
   {
            crc = _crc16_update(crc, ptr[i]);
   }

    return crc;
  }
```

This function fails compilation with:

```
 cannot convert 'ConfigT*' to 'uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}' in initialization
```

...at the following line:

```
 uint8_t *ptr = &Config;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass the address of `crc` to `_crc16_update` in order for it to modify it.  If you don't, and it's not a compile error, at best you can expect undefined behavior.

```
_crc16_update(&crc, *(ptr+i));
```

Also, you can use array notation on your `struct` byte array instead of pointer notation.  Both forms work identically, however, the first may better show that you're working with a byte array:

```
  _crc16_update(&crc, ptr[i]);
```

Comment: Ah good eye. It's suppose to be crc = _crc16_update(). That's an error on my part

Comment: @chris12892 That makes sense now.

Comment: I updated the original question to fix the crc uint16 issue. Using array notation fails with compiler error Error 6 no match for 'operator[]' in 'Config[i]'

Comment: @chris12892 Should be `ptr[i]`.  Can't access a `struct` like it's an array unless you cast it to a fixed width type like you had before.

Comment: ah, I see. See the latest update to the question. This still fails with: cannot convert 'ConfigT' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' for argument '2' to 'uint16_t _crc16_update(uint16_t, uint8_t)'

EDIT: Also, fixed the issue with sizeof(Config), it reads sizeof(ConfigT) now. Same error though.

Comment: @chris12892 Please add all errors (copy and paste) to your question.

Comment: @chris12892 Originally you had it like this: `uint8_t *ptr = &Config;`.  That is correct.

Comment: Try this: `uint8_t *ptr = (uint8_t *)&Config;`

Comment: That produces: cast from 'ConfigT*' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' loses precision [-fpermissive] on *uint8_t *ptr = (uint8_t)&Config;*

Comment: You're not reading what I'm writing carefully enough.  `uint8_t *ptr = (uint8_t *)&Config;`.  The address of `Config` is being typecast to an `uint8_t` pointer (`uint8_t *`).  Notice the `*`.

Comment: OK, my mistake. This seems to work now that I made that change. Thank you.

Comment: Good luck with the rest of your program.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign different pointer types to each other because they're incompatible. If in need, you must explicitly cast it to the other type

```
uint8_t *ptr = (uint8_t *)&Config;
```

Or better, declare _crc16_update as `_crc16_update(uint16_t *crc, void* data, int length);` and loop inside the function, not call it for each byte

Comment: Are you the same Lưu Vĩnh Phúc born in 1837? http://vi.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C6%B0u_V%C4%A9nh_Ph%C3%BAc

Comment: @FiddlingBits not sure if he was my ancestor though, but I don't think so

Comment: Just trying to make a joke... but I messed up my English. lol